# aws iam policy for serverless framework, only allow to delete deployment buckets

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, serverless-framework

I am using the serverless framework for deployment to aws. I would like to define a policy, that allows all resources to be created necessary for the serverless framework. However, I do not want the user to get full access to s3. In particular, only delete the buckets containing the specific string `-serverlessdeploymentbucket-`, none else.

Here is an attempt that is not working, as serverless gives the error of access denied when deploying.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*-serverlessdeploymentbucket-*/*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:DeleteBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*-serverlessdeploymentbucket-*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:CreateBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "cloudformation:*",
                "logs:*",
                "iam:*",
                "apigateway:*",
                "lambda:*",
                "ec2:DescribeSecurityGroups",
                "ec2:DescribeSubnets",
                "ec2:DescribeVpcs",
                "ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces",
                "events:*",
                "ssm:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```